# how to make ajax answer for slim?

Tags: ajax, slim-lang

in destroy.js.erb it works

`$("<%= escape_javascript(render @comment) %>").appendTo("#commentlist");`

how to do it for slim? 
I have tried

`$("= escape_javascript(render @comment)").appendTo("#commentlist");`

and renamed to destroy.js.slim, but its not works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Slim tries to convert your code into HTML markup, so your current code produces an error. You can check it by viewing `http://<website_adress>/something/destroy.js`

To fix this, you have to use pipe symbol, here is excerpt from official documentation:

> The pipe tells Slim to just copy the line. It essentially escapes any processing. Each following line that is indented greater than the pipe is copied over.
>
> http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames

Also, ruby embedding work a bit different for Slim, you have to use `#{ruby code}` instead of equal sign, if you embedding it into string.

To sum things up this is how it should look like to work:

```
|
   $("#{escape_javascript(render @comment)}").appendTo("#commentlist");
```

This way you can add more lines without prepending code with pipe each time.
Just to note, there is also shortcut for `escape_javascript` called simply `j`, so you could've used this code:

```
|
   $("#{j(render @comment)}").appendTo("#commentlist");
```

Answer (score 0):

in view

```
- url_ajax = 'http://gilcierweb.com.br'
- content_for :js do
  javascript:
    var ids = new Array();
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        ids.push($(this).val());
        $('.' + id).fadeOut("slow").hide(1600).remove();
      });
     $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "#{escape_javascript(url_ajax)}",
              data: {id_img: ids},
              success: function (data) {
                $('.contestants_list').append(data);
              }
            });
```

in layout

```
   -if content_for?(:js)
      == yield(:js)
```